# Plot dataframe in R in a for loop

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe named as "data":

```
Sal T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6
29.0    4.00    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
29.5    7.50    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
30.0    10.40   1.50    NA  NA  NA  NA
30.5    12.50   6.00    NA  NA  NA  NA
31.0    14.50   9.00    NA  NA  NA  NA
31.5    16.25   11.50   4.00    NA  NA  NA
32.0    18.00   13.50   7.50    NA  NA  NA
32.5    19.50   15.25   10.00   1.50    NA  NA
33.0    20.90   17.00   12.20   5.55    NA  NA
33.5    22.40   18.50   14.10   8.50    NA  NA
34.0    23.60   20.00   16.05   11.00   4.0 NA
34.5    24.90   21.50   17.50   13.00   7.1 NA
35.0    NA  22.75   19.20   14.70   9.7 1.5
35.5    NA  23.90   20.50   16.50   11.9    5.5
```

I need to plot all columns with respect to column 1 in one graph. I can do it one by one by adding points and lines to the initial plot. For example:

```
mydata1 = na.omit(data[1:2])
plot(mydata1)
lines(mydata1,col=1)
mydata2 = na.omit(data.frame(c(data[1]),c(data[3])))
points(mydata2, col =2)
lines(mydata2,col=2)
```

But it is too tedious. I am thinking using for loop to plot all at once. But it seems only plotting the last one:

```
for (i in 2:ncol(data)){
  mydata = na.omit(data.frame(c(data[1]),c(data[i])))
  plot(mydata)
  lines(mydata)
}
```

How do I do this in R? Thanks for any help.

Here is the final solution:

```
plot(0,0,xlim=c(28,37),ylim=c(0,25),type="n",ylab = "T", xlab = "Sal")

for (i in 2:ncol(data)){
  mydata = na.omit(data.frame(c(data[1]),c(data[i])))
  lines(mydata, col = i)
  legendN = colnames(data)
  legendN = legendN[2:7]
  legend("topleft", legend = legendN, col= 2:7, pch=1) # optional legend
}
```

Comment: Maybe throw `plot()` *outside* the loop? Lines and points leave in the loop.

Comment: Won't working in that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, I suggest you to take `plot` outside `for` loop, and leave `lines` in the loop.

At second, you did not scale the axes properly.

**1.dat:**

```
Sal T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6
29.0 4.00 NA NA NA NA NA
29.5 7.50 NA NA NA NA NA
30.0 10.40 1.50 NA NA NA NA
30.5 12.50 6.00 NA NA NA NA
31.0 14.50 9.00 NA NA NA NA
31.5 16.25 11.50 4.00 NA NA NA
32.0 18.00 13.50 7.50 NA NA NA
32.5 19.50 15.25 10.00 1.50 NA NA
33.0 20.90 17.00 12.20 5.55 NA NA
33.5 22.40 18.50 14.10 8.50 NA NA
34.0 23.60 20.00 16.05 11.00 4.0 NA
34.5 24.90 21.50 17.50 13.00 7.1 NA
35.0 NA 22.75 19.20 14.70 9.7 1.5
35.5 NA 23.90 20.50 16.50 11.9 5.5
```

**Code:**

```
x11()
data1 <- read.table("1.dat", header=TRUE, sep = " ", check.names=FALSE, as.is=TRUE)
plot(0,0,xlim=c(28,37),ylim=c(0,25),type="n",xlab="X",ylab="Y")

for (i in 2:ncol(data1)){
mydata = na.omit(data.frame(c(data1[1]),c(data1[i])))
lines(mydata)
}
Sys.sleep(10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Both of your solutions are good, but I can choose one as the answer for this problem. I pasted the final code based on ur suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

You could also melt the data and use `ggplot2`

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
#data1 <- as in @John_West's post
dat <- data.table(data1)
melted <- melt(dat,id.vars="Sal",variable.factor=F)

> melted
     Sal variable value
 1: 29.0       T1  4.00
 2: 29.5       T1  7.50
 3: 30.0       T1 10.40
 4: 30.5       T1 12.50
 5: 31.0       T1 14.50
 6: 31.5       T1 16.25
 7: 32.0       T1 18.00
 8: 32.5       T1 19.50
 9: 33.0       T1 20.90
10: 33.5       T1 22.40
11: 34.0       T1 23.60
12: 34.5       T1 24.90
13: 35.0       T1    NA
14: 35.5       T1    NA
15: 29.0       T2    NA
16: 29.5       T2    NA
17: 30.0       T2  1.50
18: 30.5       T2  6.00
19: 31.0       T2  9.00
20: 31.5       T2 11.50
...

ggplot(melted,aes(x=Sal,y=value,group=variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image: ggplot of values by variable on y vs original first column on x]

Incidentally this strategy makes it easy to distinguish the data by the kind of observation as well:

```
ggplot(melted,aes(x=Sal,y=value,color=variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image: Same with coloring of line segments by variable]

Comment: Thanks! Both of your solutions are good, but I can choose one as the answer for this problem.